# Node access multiple databases

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, oracle

I want to connect to different databases on server side so I can perform queries that include those two databases using node.

I have a `config.js` like this:

```
module.exports = {
    database: {
        user: 'brunojs',
        password: 'bdpf5',
        connectString: 'localhost:1521/orcl'
    },
    jwtSecretKey: "jmvhDdDBMvqb=M@6h&QVA7x"
};
```

This saves my info for accessing the first database.

Then I have one `list.js` file which performs the query:

```
var oracledb = require('oracledb');
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var config = require(__dirname + '../../config.js');

function get(req, res, next) {
    oracledb.getConnection(
        config.database,
        function(err, connection){
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            connection.execute(
                'select num_sequencial, notes, des_especialidade, dt_diag ' +
                'from organite_repository ',
                {},//no binds
                {
                    outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT
                },
                function(err, results){
                    if (err) {
                        connection.release(function(err) {
                            if (err) {
                                console.error(err.message);
                            }
                        });

                        return next(err);
                    }

                    res.status(200).json(results.rows);

                    connection.release(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error(err.message);
                        }
                    });
                }
            );
        }
    );
}

module.exports.get = get;
```

Everything works fine.

The thing is, right now, I want to perform queries using another database. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

the right solution is to use pool https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/doc/api.md#createpool
Creating massive pool:

```
module.exports = {
    database: [{user: 'brunojs',
                password: 'bdpf5',
                connectString: 'localhost:1521/orcl',
                poolAlias:'database1'
               },
               {user: 'brunojs',
                password: 'bdpf5',
                connectString: 'localhost2:1521/orcl',
                poolAlias:'database2'
               }],
    jwtSecretKey: "jmvhDdDBMvqb=M@6h&QVA7x"
};
```

during initialization web-server, initialize the pools

```
const dbConfig = require('../config/database.js');
async function initialize() {
  dbConfig.database.forEach(async function(item) {
    const pool = await oracledb.createPool(item);
  });
}
```

Then you can use the created pools when calling the connection procedure:

```
conn = await oracledb.getConnection('database1');
 const execresult = await conn.execute(context.execsql, execbinds, context.opts);
```

Answer (score 1):

First, add a second credentials object in your `config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    database: {
        user: 'brunojs',
        password: 'bdpf5',
        connectString: 'localhost:1521/orcl'
    },
    database2: {
        user: 'user2',
        password: 'password',
        connectString: 'someotherhost:1521/orcl'
    },
    jwtSecretKey: "jmvhDdDBMvqb=M@6h&QVA7x"
};
```

then use one or other here:

```
oracledb.getConnection(
    config.database, // you could change this line to config.database2
    function(err, connection){
         if (err) { ...
```

If you want to query one database, then another, you'd need to keep references to both `connection` objects (error checking omitted for brevity):

```
oracledb.GetConnection(
    config.database,
    function(err, connection1) {
        oracledb.GetConnection(
            config.database2,
            function(err, connection2) {
                // in this function you can use either connection object
                connection1.execute(...);
                connection2.execute(...);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so mych paul.
What if I wanted to perform a query using the two databases?

Answer (score 1):

This is slightly out of scope for your question, but you could also take a look at [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline).  It supports setting up multiple databases and then tying models to them, so that knowing where certain data models are stored is abstracted away.

Answer (score 1):

you can always use links on the DB side, so your java code does not have to connect to another DB, for example:

```
select num_sequencial, notes, des_especialidade, dt_diag 
from organite_repository@linkA
UNION
select num_sequencial, notes, des_especialidade, dt_diag 
from organite_repository@linkB
/* ... */
```